Inverse limits of complete metric spaces is Baire
It is well known that arbitrary products of complete metric spaces are Baire (refer to Dugundji, example).
But, what happens when one considers inverse limits of complete metric spaces over an arbitrary directed set? More generally, are closed subspaces of arbitrary products of complete metric spaces always Baire?

Minor observation: in the case of a countable index set, the product and its closed subspaces are themselves complete metric, hence Baire.

An (uncountable) inverse limit of completely metrisable spaces can fail to be
Baire. A useful motto here is "inverse limits are like generalised
intersections". This suggests that we should first ask ourselves about actual
intersections. The following fact makes what we need formal:

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ is a downward-directed
family of subsets of $X$ (meaning that for any $i, j$, there is some $k$ such
that $X_k \subseteq X_i \cap X_j$), all equipped with the subspace topology.
Consider the inverse system given by the inclusion maps
$\iota_{ij}: X_i \hookrightarrow X_j$ whenever $X_i \subseteq X_j$
(we're viewing $I$ as a directed set via the reverse-inclusion
relation on the subsets: $i \preceq j$ iff $X_i \supseteq X_j$).
Then the inverse limit of this system is given by $L = \bigcap_{i \in I} X_i$
in the subspace topology, equipped with the inclusion maps
$\iota_i: L \hookrightarrow X_i$.

I won't write out the whole proof. Basically, to show this, you just need to
show that $L$ has the right universal property. This is mostly a matter of
writing down the definitions and staring at them a bit, and trying not to get
confused about which direction everything is going in.
With this fact in hand, we are good to go. Consider $X = (0, 1)$, and consider
the family of all subspaces $X_i \subseteq X$ such that $X \setminus X_i$ is a
finite set of irrationals. This family is downward-directed, and every such $X_i$
is completely metrisable because it's a finite union of open intervals. However,
the intersection is $\Bbb Q \cap (0, 1)$ which is not a Baire space.
